# High-efficiency, battery powered high-side load driver

Tags: mosfet, dc-dc-converter, mosfet-driver, battery-operated, high-side

I need to drive a resistive load with low-voltage and relatively high current, in a battery powered system. Since I need my load to be grounded, I would like to use a push-pull or high-side drive. I am oriented towards maximixing simplicity over cost, and therefore I always choose off-the-shelf and ready-to-use solutions when available. I will drive my load from a 3.3V logic, with a square PWM signal and a carrier frequency of 500 Hz. The system is powered from a 3.7V battery, with the voltage varying among 2.7 to 4.2V. Obviously, the 3.3V voltage line to the microcontroller is stabilized with a buck-boost converter. The load will instead drain power directly from the battery, to avoid efficiency losses. I had some difficulties finding low-voltage half bridge mosfet drivers (except from the MAX15492, which unfortunately has no stock) and I focused in high-side mosfet drivers instead. After a long search, I found the [LTC1981](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/19812fs.pdf), and I drew the circuit below

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fk1iGp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I studied the datasheet throughly but I still have some doubts: the VCC power voltage will vary among 4.2V when the battery is fully charged, to 2.7V when it is depleted. On the other side the PWM signal to SHDN will always be between 3.3V and GND. The datasheet clearly states that this is possible, but I wonder if I missed anything? Moreover, I am trying to select a mosfet with lowest possible Rdson, low Voltage threshold and faily low gate input capacitance. I need to switch at 500 Hz, which is not a high frequency, but I really want to minimize losses and save battery. Did I choose the right mosfet ([DMN1008UFDF](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/DMN1008UFDF.pdf))?